# Некорректное отображение Banner AdMob на Sony Xperia Z3

Tags: android, unity3d, firebase, admob

После импорта **Firebase Analytics** і **Firebase Messaging** нижний баннер (`AdPosition.Bottom`) **AdMob** отображается тонкой линией, будто его обрезали.

Баг воспроизводиться на телефоне *Sony Xperia Z3* (Android 6.0.1), на *Lenovo* норм работает.

```
public void RequestBanner()
{
    BannerView bannerV = new BannerView(_adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Center);
    BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(_adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);

    AdRequest requestV = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice(GameManager._Instance.DeviceId.ToUpper()).Build();
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice(GameManager._Instance.DeviceId.ToUpper()).Build();

    bannerV.LoadAd(requestV);
    bannerView.LoadAd(request);

    bannerV.Show(); 
    bannerView.Show();  
}
```

На изображении видно, что проблема именно с нижним баннером:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил строку `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` в файл *"Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml"* **:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="${applicationId}"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
               android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <!-- The MessagingUnityPlayerActivity is a class that extends
         UnityPlayerActivity to work around a known issue when receiving
         notification data payloads in the background. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.MessageForwardingService"
             android:exported="false"/>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

И всё, проблема решена:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иследуя вопрос заметил, что у людей та же проблема встечается при тестировании приложения именно на *Sony Xperia*.

На случай если моё решение не поможет, есть другие идеи на [англоязычном источнике](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/576).